# What is the intersection of the closures of left invertible operators and right invertible operators?

Tags: operator-theory, fa.functional-analysis, banach-spaces

From Douglas Zare's answer (see [Does $X$ embed in $Y$, and $Y$ embed in $X$, always imply  that $X$ isomorphic onto $Y$?](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/99777/does-x-embed-in-y-and-y-embed-in-x-always-imply-that-x-isomorphic-on)), one know that 
$$ \overline{G_{l}(X,Y)} \bigcap \overline{G_{r}(X,Y) } = \overline{G(X,Y)}$$ 
does not hold in general, where 
$G_{l}((X,Y),G_{r}((X,Y)$ and $G(X,Y)$ 
denote the set of left invertible operators, right invertible operators and invertible operators. (We say an operator $T$ left invertible, if $ST=I$ for some operator $S$.)
But does this equality holds when $X=Y$? If not, for what kinds of $X$, this equality holds? Furthermore, does this equality holds when $B(X)$ is replaced by a Banach algebra $A$ with an identity?

Comment: I think you need to clarify your last sentence. Do you mean: "does this equality hold when $B(X)$ is replaced by an arbitrary Banach algebra $A$"?

Comment: Thanks Choi. Yes, the last sentence should be "does this equality hold when $B(X)$ is replaced by an arbitrary Banach algebra $A$ with an identity".

Comment: The tags on this question need editing. (As far as I know, I do not have enough reputation to do this myself.)

Comment: are you talking about *bounded* operators? and hence taking the closure in the operator norm?